# How to split values by comma from object values - django2

Tags: django

I have this output when i print the actual code on my template:

> item1,item2,item3

with this code:

```
related = Product.objects.filter(topic__icontains=topic).values('related').first()
```

and i try  with .split(',') but i get a blank result

i can print:

> {'related': tutorials,news,information'}

i need:

> link1: tutorial , link2 news, link3 information

I can create one backlink in each one to diferents urls,
Is for add related topic links, i can split the data from related variable or i need take other way?

Comment: Isn't the result a dictionary? What is `related`?

Comment: hi, in related h have all the text with commas, i need split this for create a list of backlinks to related categories, wit this i have in related a text like: news,tutorials,information, but in 1 like all togheter

Comment: But that is perhaps in the template. The type of `related` should be a dictionary. What if you `print(related)`.

Comment: if i print related i got the querydict:related:news,techonology,tutorials etc but all in one line

Comment: A `querydict`? That looks like a `request.POST`/`request.GET`, not a Django ORM query.

Comment: look i receive exactly this:

{'related': tutorials,news,information'}

Comment: Do you want to get list of dicts, such as `list_a = [{'link': 'tutuorial'}, {'link': 'news'}, ....]` ?

Comment: yes i want print the links to each category, so i need split the words by comma and create the link

Comment: Can you show all `print(related)`?

Comment: if i do that i get: {'related': tutorials,news,information'} but i need split each word by comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need split result because you get 'related' field from db as one string. I think something like this:

```
related = Product.objects.filter(topic__icontains=topic).values('related').first()
links_list = [{'link': item} for item in related.get('related').split(',')]
print(links_list)
```

And you'll get list of dicts with key link.

Comment: with these code i get:[{'link': 'news'}, {'link': 'tutorials'}, {'link': 'information'}

Comment: Is it what you'll want?

Comment: no, i think you misunderstood the word link is a reference for declare a a href="" atribute i need create the backlinks on these order, separated by comma

Comment: You 'll get list of separeted comma values, so you can do with this values all you want, create href atributes as you want and others. I am not understanding all your context.